# Spring rolls splitting when frozen

Tags: freezing, pastry, frozen

I was wondering if anyone knew why my spring rolls split when I freeze them? They are a larger spring roll, filled with veges, noodles & meat. I wrap them in 2 sheets of pastry and I put them in a container 3 spring rolls deep. It's not the weight of the spring rolls on top because the top layer are just as split as the bottom layer. They also get quite soggy when defrosting due to the condensation in the container melting.
Thanks

Comment: Water expands when it freezes. Veg, noodles and meat are full of water. 'Do the math' :)

Answer (score 4):

Water expands when it freezes, so you probably have an excess of water in the spring rolls that is causing the skins to break when you freeze them. Try draining the filling as much as you can before freezing them, or leaving a bit of excess room when you wrap them.

Comment: In addition, you can try staging the freezing process by refrigerating first as the rapidity of expansion may be an issue. Also, adding some salt while draining will draw out water when in a colander

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody said, water expands when it freezes - ice occupies 4% more volume than liquid water.

SO set out your fillings on a tray, separated into "sticks", and freeze that trayful of fillings first. Get your pastry and use it to wrap the frozen filling sticks. Freeze those, they won't split.